# Post api github

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Olá,

Estou com problema na hora de fazer um post para a api do github, recebo esse erro no mozilla:

Requisição cross-origin bloqueada: A política de mesma origem (Same Origin Policy) impede a leitura do recurso remoto em https://api.github.com/repos/marcobrito/frontEnd/issues. (Motivo: símbolo 'access-control-allow-origin' faltando no cabeçalho CORS 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' durante a pré-conexão CORS).

E no Chrome:

https://api.github.com/repos/marcobrito/frontEnd/issues 401 (Unauthorized)

Segue o meu code:

```
myApp.controller('postCtrl', function($scope, $http){
    $scope.form = {};

        $scope.submitForm = function() {
        $http({
          method  : 'POST',
          url     : 'https://api.github.com/repos/marcobrito/frontEnd/issues',
          data    : $scope.form, //forms user object
          headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Authorization': '094a87044657ca7859dd9b151a08d53ae4a0bad2', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', 'Status': '203'} 
         })
          .success(function(data) {
            if (data.errors) {

            } else {
              console.log(errors)
            }
          });
        };
    });
```

Alguém pode me ajudar?